# Не получается подключить fancybox

Tags: javascript, html, css

Хочу подкючить fancybox но на сайте не он не отоброжается . в чем проблема ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще картинки :

https://ibb.co/qrMBFZG

https://ibb.co/59HQZbj

Comment: Можно ваш html и css сюда вставить?

Comment: Сюда по картинкам, Вы только стили подключили, а нужно еще и сам плагин подключить. Он с расширением .js.

Comment: вот изменил на js / всеравно не работает . https://codepen.io/terema001/pen/QWyrVJQ

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример подключения "рандомных" картинок на вашем сайте. Подключения css и js плагина используйте те, которые я привел в данном примере. Добавлен контейнер documentsGallery с картинками. Думаю, разберетесь. Если будут вопросы. Обращайтесь.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-fancybox="images"]').fancybox({
    buttons : [ 
      'zoom',
      'fullScreen',
      'close'
    ],
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #5e5e5e;
}

*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul,li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}

.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

header {
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.header__top {
  background-color: #303030;
}

.header__btn {
  float: right;
  line-height: 36px;
  color: #1b1b1b;
 background: #ffcc22;
 padding: 5px 20px 4px 50px;
 font-size: 16px;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
}

.header__btn:before {
  content: "\f0b1";
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  position: absolute;
  color: #1b1b1b;
  left: 22px;
}

.header__contacts:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}


.header__email, .header__phone {
color: #b2b2b2;
font-size: 14px;
letter-spacing: 0.25px;
line-height: 45px;
position: relative;
}

.header__phone {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.header__phone:before {
  content: "\f095";
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  position: absolute;
  color: #ffc222;
  left: 0;
}

.header__email {
  padding-left: 24px;
}

.header__email:before {
  content: "\f003";
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  position: absolute;
  color: #ffc222;
  left: 0;
}

.header-content {
  padding: 34px 0px 24px; 
}

.header__content-inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu a {
  color: #323232;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 34px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.menu a:hover {
  border-color: #ffc222;
}

.menu li + li {
  padding-left: 10px;

}

/*Добавлен*/
.documentsGallery {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 100px 0 100px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.7/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.7/jquery.fancybox.min.css">



   <header class="header">
      <div class="header__top">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="header__contacts">
               <a class="header__phone" href="tel:37067648839">+37067648839</a>
               <a class="header__email" href="">layoout@gmail.com</a>
               <a data-fancybox data-src="#modal" href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary" class="header__btn" href="">бесплатная консультация</a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>  


      <div class="header-content">
         <div class="container"> 
            <div class="header__content-inner">
               <div class="header__logo">
                  <a href="#">
                     <img src="LOGOTYPE.png" alt="">
                  </a>
               </div>

               <nav class="menu">
                  <ul>
                     <li><a  href="#">Главная </a></li>
                     <li><a  href="#">О компании</a></li>
                     <li><a  href="#">Услуги</a></li>
                     <li><a  href="#">Контакты</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </nav>

            </div>
         </div>
         
         
         
         <div class="documentsGallery">      
            <a href="https://static.dochkisinochki.ru/upload/img_loader/c0/fb/f5/GL001101203_001.JPG" data-fancybox="images">
                <img src="https://static.dochkisinochki.ru/upload/resize_cache/img_loader/7b/40/a6/50_50_1/GL001101203_002.JPG">
            </a>
            <a href="https://static.dochkisinochki.ru/upload/img_loader/c0/fb/f5/GL001101203_001.JPG" data-fancybox="images">
                <img src="https://static.dochkisinochki.ru/upload/resize_cache/img_loader/7b/40/a6/50_50_1/GL001101203_002.JPG">
            </a>
            <a href="https://static.dochkisinochki.ru/upload/img_loader/c0/fb/f5/GL001101203_001.JPG" data-fancybox="images">
                <img src="https://static.dochkisinochki.ru/upload/resize_cache/img_loader/7b/40/a6/50_50_1/GL001101203_002.JPG">
            </a>
            <a href="https://static.dochkisinochki.ru/upload/img_loader/c0/fb/f5/GL001101203_001.JPG" data-fancybox="images">
                <img src="https://static.dochkisinochki.ru/upload/resize_cache/img_loader/7b/40/a6/50_50_1/GL001101203_002.JPG">
            </a>
            <a href="https://static.dochkisinochki.ru/upload/img_loader/c0/fb/f5/GL001101203_001.JPG" data-fancybox="images">
                <img src="https://static.dochkisinochki.ru/upload/resize_cache/img_loader/7b/40/a6/50_50_1/GL001101203_002.JPG">
            </a>
         </div>



      <div style="display: none;" id="modal">
       <h2>Hello!</h2>
       <p>You are awesome!</p>
    </div>
```